# Live search and sort using jQuery from a single HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, search, split

*Hoping someone could help me with this odd problem I'm experiencing. I am not an expert with jQuery and this is one of the first few scripts I've ever written so any help would be greatly appreciated!*

I have an FAQ page with 3 main categories and 6 sub-categories. Using a single HTML list, I have implemented 2 jQuery functions that retrieves specific list items based on either using the:

1) Live search, or 
2) Selecting a sub-category link

Each of these functions work as expected individually, however...

---

**The problem**

When both functionalities are used together within a single page refresh - i.e. if a user conducts a search first, THEN select a category afterwards, the respective category list does not get populated, ***HOWEVER*** the items that showed up from the search term that returned a positive match WOULD still show up.

I suspect it's something to do with the element being hidden from the DOM and most likely the `$(this).hide();` on line 36, but I cannot for the life of me figure out a different way to write the function without using that line...

---

**Here is my JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.link-list a').each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[1];
        $(this).on('click', function(e){
            $('#' + type).show();
            $('.faq-main').hide();
            $('.faq-back').show();
            $('.faq-back').on('click', function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#' + type).hide();
                $('.no-result').hide();
                $('.faq-main').show();
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    // SEARCH
    $("#search").on('input', function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if(filter == ''){
            $(".faq-list > * > *").hide();
            $(".faq-main").show();
            $(".no-results").hide();
            $(".faq-list > * > * > p").hide();
            return;
        }

        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".faq-list div div").each(function(){

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).hide();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches
            } else {
                $(".faq-main").hide();
                $(this).show();
                $('.faq-list > * > * > h3').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/y15fycgc/)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger in the browser console? Might be worth putting a breakpoint in before the .hide() to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a class to the items you hide with search, so you can easily identify them.

```
 $(".faq-list div div").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).addClass('search-hidden');
```

Then when you respond to a click with the category link you can easily do:
    $('.link-list a').each(function(){
       $('.search-hidden').removeClass('search-hidden');

This just resets all hidden results from the previous search, revealing them again.

In your css, just handle the hiding of the items.

```
.search-hidden {display:none;}
```

Now you can quickly see through looking at your browser console which items have been hidden and by what.

In general, to make things easier on jQuery css paths, you probably want to add some class attributes to your markup to save this type of thing `.faq-list > * > * > h3`. Instead, add `class="someheader"` to the markup of the h3 tags, then you can easily write `$('.someheader').hide();`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was able to fix the conflict with the add/removeClass rather than using show/hide. Also learned something new!